# Oauth for webserver based chrome extensions like bookmarking extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, oauth, google-chrome-extension, bookmarklet

I was wondering how does bookmarking extensions like diigo use oauth. I mean i know there exists oauth client side flow for extensions and installed applications. However for bookmarking extensions, the authentication needs to happen at the server side. But one side effect of this approach is that, when extensions are first loaded, they have no way to know whether user is logged in or not and hence have to perform the 3-legged oauth flow everytime. However, I don't this this happens for any of the bookmarking extensions, as when i start a new chrome instance with a diigo/deleicious extension, i don't see any new tab opening and trying to authorize me using oauth. I am trying to build a chrome extensions which also needs to use server side flow for auth, but am not sure how to make the chrome extension automatically login when it is first loaded.

Comment: can you show some example i can look and may be able to provide some inputs as i am nor aware about all this extension stuff

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_oauth.html This will give you a perspective on oAuth for google chrome extensions.